# open link authentication using scrapy

Tags: scrapy

hello I have a trouble using scrapy
I want to scrap some data from clinicalkey.com
I have a id, password for my hospital and my hospital has authority of clinicalkey.com

so if I log in to my hospital's library page, I also can use clincalkey.com without authentication

But My scrapy script didn't work. I can't findout why this is not working

My script here

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(loginsite, formdata={'id': 'Myid', 'password': 'MyPassword'}, callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request(clinicalkeysite, callback=self.parse_datail)

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        blahblah
```

When I see the final response, It has message about "You need login"..

Answer (score 0):

This site use json body form for authenification.
Try something like this:

```
body = '{"username":"{}","password":"{}","remember_me":true,"product":"CK_US"}'.format(yourname, yourpassword)
yield scrapy.FormRequest(loginsite, body=body, callback=self.after_login)
```